# js function works on pc desktop but not on ios iphone

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone

I have the following snippet that works on my pc desktop.  It works there but not on my iphone.

```js
function dateFormat(date,type){    
    
    let dayOfWeek = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'];
    let month = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
    date.replaceAll("-","/");   
    
    date = new Date(date + " EDT");     
    
    function daySuffix(d) {
      if (d > 3 && d < 21) return d + 'th';
      switch (d % 10) {
        case 1:  return d + "st";
        case 2:  return d + "nd";
        case 3:  return d + "rd";
        default: return d + "th";
      }
    }
    let day = daySuffix(date.getDate());
    
    let string = "";
    
    switch(type){
       case 'ld': string = dayOfWeek[date.getDay()] + ", " + month[date.getMonth()] + " " + day;break;
       case 'sd': string =  month[date.getMonth()] + " " + day;break;
       default: string =  "wrong type, ld or sd only";
    }
    console.log(string,'string');
    return string;
 }
 
 console.log(dateFormat("2022-05-06","ld"))
```

Comment: this is a minimal reproducible example.  what more do you want?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with timezone that is appended to date string  `EDT`. It is making incorrect date string `"2022-05-06 EDT"`.
You may archive setting timezone by formatting date and parsing it back (still it has no impact on date only dates).

```js
function dateFormat(date,type){    
    
    let dayOfWeek = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'];
    let month = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']; 
    
    date = new Date(new Date(date).toLocaleString('en-US', {
      timeZone: "America/Detroit"
    }));
    
    function daySuffix(d) {
      if (d > 3 && d < 21) return d + 'th';
      switch (d % 10) {
        case 1:  return d + "st";
        case 2:  return d + "nd";
        case 3:  return d + "rd";
        default: return d + "th";
      }
    }
    let day = daySuffix(date.getDate());
    
    let string = "";
    
    switch(type){
       case 'ld': string = dayOfWeek[date.getDay()] + ", " + month[date.getMonth()] + " " + day;break;
       case 'sd': string =  month[date.getMonth()] + " " + day;break;
       default: string =  "wrong type, ld or sd only";
    }
    console.log(string,'string');
    return string;
 }
 
 console.log(dateFormat("2022-05-06","ld"))
```

Comment: It is correct ecma262 date-only string: "This format includes date-only forms: YYYY, YYYY-MM, YYYY-MM-DD" https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format

Answer (score 0):

the problem is just with this line:

```
date.replaceAll("-","/");
```

it needs to be:

```
date = date.replaceAll("-","/");
```

```js
function dateFormat(date,type){    
    
    let dayOfWeek = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'];
    let month = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
    date = date.replaceAll("-","/");   
    
    date = new Date(date + " EDT");     
    
    function daySuffix(d) {
      if (d > 3 && d < 21) return d + 'th';
      switch (d % 10) {
        case 1:  return d + "st";
        case 2:  return d + "nd";
        case 3:  return d + "rd";
        default: return d + "th";
      }
    }
    let day = daySuffix(date.getDate());
    
    let string = "";
    
    switch(type){
       case 'ld': string = dayOfWeek[date.getDay()] + ", " + month[date.getMonth()] + " " + day;break;
       case 'sd': string =  month[date.getMonth()] + " " + day;break;
       default: string =  "wrong type, ld or sd only";
    }
    console.log(string,'string');
    return string;
 }
 
 console.log(dateFormat("2022-05-06","ld"))
```